# Using PHP Simple DOM Parser to get image from Wordpress Post

Tags: php, html, wordpress, http, dom

I am using the open source PHP library known as [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to scrape the first image of a Wordpress Post. If I call the main website:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://iadorefood.com/');
```

I get a response, an object of the DOM that I can manipulate. But if I request the URL of a specific post, my object returns *NULL*. Here is my command:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://iadorefood.com/articles/tuscany-san-gimignano/');
```

Why does my object return NULL? Is there something wrong with the URL?

Comment: Are there limitations in the parser (for size or supported elements)? Or does the page of the post contain errors (whereas the main does not)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://iadorefood.com/articles/tuscany-san-gimignano');
$element =  $html->find('div.content p img');
echo '<img src=' . $element[0]->src . ' />';
```

It's tested and working, notice the trailing `/` at the URL, I've removed it and works fine.